# Custom update_email method for Devise user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I would like to have an endpoint for a controller than handles updating the emails of Devise users. Ideally, when a user submits a new email with their current password, it would behave as if I submitted the default `edit` form packaged in Devise.

I have enabled `config.reconfirmable` in my devise configs. However, whenever I try typing in something like:

```
User.find(1).update_with_password(email: 'asdf@email.com', password: 'currentpass')
```

in the rails console, it rollbacks the DB update

```
User Exists (0.4ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."email" = 'asdf@email.com' AND "users"."id" != 1) LIMIT 1
```

When I test out the confirmation emails in the console

```
User.find(1).send_confirmation_instructions
```

it works as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading through the documentation, you must use `current_password` as your key for the user's password.

```
User.find(1).update_with_password(email: 'asdf@email.com', current_password: 'currentpass')
```